# deploy a swift-storage in juju

Tags: juju

deploying the swift-storage in a vnode after the status the result is this

```
  swift-storage-zone2:
    charm: cs:trusty/swift-storage-2
    exposed: false
    units:
      swift-storage-zone2/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "install"'
        agent-version: 1.20.1
        machine: "7"
        public-address: ccsvr1node8.maas
```

someone knows why it gives me this error? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to ssh into the machine `juju ssh swift-storage-zone2/0` then go to `/var/log/juju` and inspect the log files to see what may have failed.

Comment: I don't find any directory called juju in that path!

Comment: this is the situation about swift-storage on juju deploy (http://paste.ubuntu.com/7885051/) the agent-state is down